# jQuery - multiple step wizard form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple wizard form that navigates through steps.
I know there are plenty of plugins out there but I just like to make my own.

I have a problem with the `>>` button that is supposed to display the next step.

```
var current = $('.pg-wrapper div').hasClass('current');
var index = $('.pg-wrapper').index(current);

$(function () {
  $('.pg-wrapper div').not('.current').hide();
}(jQuery));


$('#next').on('click', function() {
  current.next().addClass('current');
  current.removeClass('current');
});
```

Here is the full sample [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/anuCAbI/9/edit)

Comment: what is the problem tell us ?

Comment: `hasClass` retunes a boolean value not a jQuery object, what's wrong with using a simple class selector?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Multiple step form (wizard)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672384/jquery-multiple-step-form-wizard)

Comment: I complicated the matter. I could have just assigned $('.current') instead. Thanks for pointing this out. There seems to be more problems since `next` button still does not work.

Comment: @Seong Lee: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672384/jquery-multiple-step-form-wizard/18672598#18672598

Comment: You want to achieve this: http://jsbin.com/oxamOBA/1/ ? I got the question?

Comment: Can you include your HTML? Otherwise it is hard to understand why things are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have some issues:

- hasClass: return a boolean value and tells you if you selector have
  or not a class
- index: is useless
- in your next click function you are changing the class but not
  toggling the visibility
- the steps bar is not handled

With this code seems to working fine; check the use of `find('.current')` the get the current step child of `.pg-wrapper` and the use of `next` to move across the siblings.

Code:

```
var current;
var navstep;
$(function () {
   current = $('.pg-wrapper').find('.current');
  navstep=$('.nav-step').find('.active');
  $('.pg-wrapper div').not(current).hide();
}(jQuery));


$('#next').on('click', function() {
  if (current.next().length==0) return
  current.next().addClass('current').show();
  current.removeClass('current').hide();

    navstep.next().addClass('active');
  navstep.removeClass('active');

 current = current.next();
  navstep=navstep.next();
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/oxamOBA/1/edit